# Render doesn't looks like what I'm seeing from the Camera View

Tags: 3d-view, filmic-blender

as the title say I don't know why but what the rendering shows is not corresponding to the Camera View I choose. I have only one camera but it seems like when I hit the rendering option it uses another POV where the camera is located parallel to the ground at Z=0 and perpendicular ti the Z plane. How do i Fix this?
Here's some screenshots.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems to be you have set some object as camera. You have selected local camera also, but this setting works in 3D-view only, hence it is not affected on render.

I suggest you select camera and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Num 0</kbd>. Active camera has solid triangle above - double-check that you have it

[image]

Also, you have an object "Cube", which is hidden but active in Render. It is possible that it blocks the camera view

Comment: Basically the problem is that while I can use a linket object to move a camera, when I hav eto render the camera view the object needs to be delated? How can I still keep the linking in between the object and the camera while also having the camera view being the one that renders the image? Sorry for those questions I'm a beginner.

Comment: You should parent camera to object using Ctrl+P (object should be selected second) so that camera position will depend on object.

Comment: Ok, now I have only ONE camera and it has the black triangle active, and its showing exatly what I wanted to render, but still when rendering it shows a very weird portion of the project in a very wierd way, I don't even know where the other "view" is pointing.

Comment: You can use any object type as camera. But if camera is active... You have an object "Cube", which is hidden but active in Render. It is possible that it bloks the camera view.